# What exactly is a "BES Router" and how is it different from BES?

Tags: blackberry, bes

I've heard the term "BES Router" used from time to time but I don't understand what it is.  I tried checking support KB articles on RIM but it still seems a little ambiguous.  Can someone please clarify?  Is this a service running on a Blackberry Enterprise Server?  Or is this a "role"?

Comment: IIRC (been a few years), it is a necessary role but doesn't have to be installed on the same server as BES.  You can place it for instance in a DMZ.

Think of it like a Hub Transport server in Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BlackBerry Router is a component of the BES server. IMO you can consider it both a role and a service within BES. You can choose to "break out" the BES Router during the install to install it on a server other than the primary BES server.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/7335/BB_Router_572521_11.jsp.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/25805/Installing_the_BB_Router_472462_11.jsp